# reading json with big numbers in spark causing rounding

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently trying to read into spark a JSON file with large numbers. unsigned 64bit longs.

When I read it in, no matter the `pyspark.sql.types` I use in my schema `LongType`, `DecimalType`, `DoubleType`, etc...

Issue : 
My numbers get rounded off. Even if I read them in as a `StringType` in my schema.

*Is there a way to read these numbers in without rounding?*

Comment: It would be more helpful, if you could update question with some sample data.

Comment: JSON is based on JavaScript which only has a single numeric type and that's floats, so I'd expect every JSON parser will have this limitation. If these numbers are IDs or such, can you consider storing them as strings instead?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it wasn't spark at all.  It was from a dump of the data with elasticdump that produced the JSON with rounded numbers.  So going to just reindex it to a string and then dump it back out again like filbranden suggested